# Can I mash two different voltages together?

Tags: voltage

Say I have a 3.7Volt Battery and a 1.5Volt Battery.

Is there a way to mash the two currents together to make 5.2volt?
Done in Series?

Dont care about the amp. Just wondering if it can be done with volt.

Comment: Why the heck are you trying to mix battery chemstries?

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

But we don't call it 'doing something to the currents', we call it 'putting in series'.

A battery of 1.5v, in series with a battery of 3.7v, will give you a total of 5.2v across the two batteries.

There are practical difficulties with using batteries of different capacity in series if you want to draw any significant charge from them, as one is likely to run down before the other, each battery needs to be watched individually for end of life. However, for simply measuring the voltage, or doing a short experiment, it's fine.